# Need to use two classes header in together in C++

Tags: c++, class, header, c++20

Hello I need to use two classes like blow

file for class c1

```
#include<iostream>
#include<variant>

class c1{
private:
...
   std::variant<c2,int,double,std::string> a;
public:
...
   c2 getA(){
     return a;
   }
};
```

and in file of class c2

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

class c2{
private:
...
   std::vector<c1> b;
public:
...
   c1 getB(){
     return b;
   }
};
```

I think my code is not such good

any one can help to fix or do this

I have use like this in blow of these two headers

```
class c1;

class c2{...};
```

but I still can't create a variable with c1 class

I can only create pointers but I can't use them correctly in the **std::variant**

and I have tried to including them but compiler get error

what can I do for fix this?

please help

**EDIT:**

> and I have tried to including them but compiler get error

this is that error

```
In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/move.h:55,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/nested_exception.h:40,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/exception:144,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ios:39,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONObject.h:9,
                 from C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONObject.cpp:5:
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits: In instantiation of 'struct std::is_trivially_destructible<JSONObject>':
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits:2846:25:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::is_trivially_destructible_v<JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:313:5:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>::_S_trivial_dtor'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:321:20:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>::_S_trivial_move_assign'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:646:16:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... _Types> using _Move_assign_alias = std::__detail::__variant::_Move_assign_base<std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<_Types>::_S_trivial_move_assign, _Types ...> [with _Types = {int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject}]'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:649:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_base<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:1038:11:   required from 'class std::variant<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONType.h:22:62:   required from here
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits:1282:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class JSONObject'
     struct is_trivially_destructible
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONObject.h:14,
                 from C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONObject.cpp:5:
C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONType.h:14:7: note: forward declaration of 'class JSONObject'
 class JSONObject;
       ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/move.h:55,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/nested_exception.h:40,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/exception:144,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ios:39,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONObject.h:9,
                 from C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONObject.cpp:5:
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits: In instantiation of 'constexpr const bool std::is_trivially_destructible_v<JSONObject>':
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:313:5:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>::_S_trivial_dtor'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:321:20:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>::_S_trivial_move_assign'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:646:16:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... _Types> using _Move_assign_alias = std::__detail::__variant::_Move_assign_base<std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<_Types>::_S_trivial_move_assign, _Types ...> [with _Types = {int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject}]'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:649:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_base<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:1038:11:   required from 'class std::variant<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONType.h:22:62:   required from here
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits:2846:25: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::is_trivially_destructible<JSONObject>'
   inline constexpr bool is_trivially_destructible_v =
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits: In instantiation of 'struct std::__is_trivially_move_constructible_impl<JSONObject, true>':
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits:1228:12:   required from 'struct std::is_trivially_move_constructible<JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits:2834:25:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::is_trivially_move_constructible_v<JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:317:5:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>::_S_trivial_move_ctor'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:523:70:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... _Types> using _Move_ctor_alias = std::__detail::__variant::_Move_ctor_base<std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<_Types>::_S_trivial_move_ctor, _Types ...> [with _Types = {int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject}]'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:526:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Copy_assign_base<false, int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:580:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Move_assign_base<false, int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:649:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_base<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:1038:11:   required from 'class std::variant<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONType.h:22:62:   required from here
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits:1221:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class JSONObject'
     struct __is_trivially_move_constructible_impl<_Tp, true>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONObject.h:14,
                 from C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONObject.cpp:5:
C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONType.h:14:7: note: forward declaration of 'class JSONObject'
 class JSONObject;
       ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/move.h:55,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/nested_exception.h:40,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/exception:144,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ios:39,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONObject.h:9,
                 from C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONObject.cpp:5:
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits: In instantiation of 'constexpr const bool std::is_trivially_move_constructible_v<JSONObject>':
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:317:5:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>::_S_trivial_move_ctor'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:523:70:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... _Types> using _Move_ctor_alias = std::__detail::__variant::_Move_ctor_base<std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<_Types>::_S_trivial_move_ctor, _Types ...> [with _Types = {int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject}]'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:526:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Copy_assign_base<false, int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:580:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Move_assign_base<false, int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:649:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_base<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:1038:11:   required from 'class std::variant<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONType.h:22:62:   required from here
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits:2834:25: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::is_trivially_move_constructible<JSONObject>'
   inline constexpr bool is_trivially_move_constructible_v =
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits: In instantiation of 'struct std::__is_trivially_copy_constructible_impl<JSONObject, true>':
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits:1207:12:   required from 'struct std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits:2831:25:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:315:5:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>::_S_trivial_copy_ctor'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:489:70:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... _Types> using _Copy_ctor_alias = std::__detail::__variant::_Copy_ctor_base<std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<_Types>::_S_trivial_copy_ctor, _Types ...> [with _Types = {int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject}]'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:492:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Move_ctor_base<false, int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:526:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Copy_assign_base<false, int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:580:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Move_assign_base<false, int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:649:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_base<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:1038:11:   required from 'class std::variant<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONType.h:22:62:   required from here
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits:1200:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class JSONObject'
     struct __is_trivially_copy_constructible_impl<_Tp, true>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONObject.h:14,
                 from C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONObject.cpp:5:
C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONType.h:14:7: note: forward declaration of 'class JSONObject'
 class JSONObject;
       ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/move.h:55,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/nested_exception.h:40,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/exception:144,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ios:39,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONObject.h:9,
                 from C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONObject.cpp:5:
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits: In instantiation of 'constexpr const bool std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<JSONObject>':
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:315:5:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>::_S_trivial_copy_ctor'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:489:70:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... _Types> using _Copy_ctor_alias = std::__detail::__variant::_Copy_ctor_base<std::__detail::__variant::_Traits<_Types>::_S_trivial_copy_ctor, _Types ...> [with _Types = {int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject}]'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:492:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Move_ctor_base<false, int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:526:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Copy_assign_base<false, int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:580:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Move_assign_base<false, int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:649:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_base<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:1038:11:   required from 'class std::variant<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONType.h:22:62:   required from here
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits:2831:25: error: 'value' is not a member of 'std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<JSONObject>'
   inline constexpr bool is_trivially_copy_constructible_v =
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits: In instantiation of 'struct std::is_literal_type<JSONObject>':
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits:2791:25:   required from 'constexpr const bool std::is_literal_type_v<JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:356:33:   recursively required from 'union std::__detail::__variant::_Variadic_union<double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:356:33:   required from 'union std::__detail::__variant::_Variadic_union<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:413:34:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_storage<false, int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:458:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Copy_ctor_base<false, int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:492:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Move_ctor_base<false, int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:526:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Copy_assign_base<false, int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:580:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Move_assign_base<false, int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:649:12:   required from 'struct std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_base<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:1038:11:   required from 'class std::variant<int, double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'
C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONType.h:22:62:   required from here
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits:698:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class JSONObject'
     struct is_literal_type
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONObject.h:14,
                 from C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONObject.cpp:5:
C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONType.h:14:7: note: forward declaration of 'class JSONObject'
 class JSONObject;
       ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/move.h:55,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/nested_exception.h:40,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/exception:144,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ios:39,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONObject.h:9,
                 from C:\Users\M\CLionProjects\MyJson\my_json\JSONObject.cpp:5:
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/type_traits: In instantiation of 'constexpr const bool std::is_literal_type_v<JSONObject>':
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/variant:356:33:   recursively required from 'union std::__detail::__variant::_Variadic_union<double, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, JSONObject>'

...

mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\MyJson.dir\build.make:75: CMakeFiles/MyJson.dir/my_json/JSONObject.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\MyJson.dir\build.make:88: CMakeFiles/MyJson.dir/my_json/JSONType.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:75: CMakeFiles/MyJson.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/MyJson.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: MyJson] Error 2
```

Comment: What is the error message you got when you include the necessary header files ? Post the error please.

Comment: Have you ever heard about header guards?

Answer (score 0):

Each class should know about internal structures (at least size of data) for correct compilation. So, you can't create cycle definition.